# How to make image sidebar responsive

Tags: css, html

I have made a sidebar. But I am unable to make it responsive such as auto-adjust the sidebar with screen size, scroll bar appears while adjusting the screen even a little. Can anyone help me how to achieve this.

I have also made a plunker for the code I made. https://plnkr.co/edit/NRSmWDAJXtgkbr6tdqrh?p=preview

```css
/* Styles go here */

.topbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #00a99d;
}
.topbar .logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}
.topbar .navbar_brand {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 0px 0px 42px;
}
.nav_content {
  float: left;
}
.side_nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 0;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.side_nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.side_nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
.side_nav .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d9d9db;
}
.side_nav li a {
  padding: 13px 0px 16px 0px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
.side_nav li a:hover {
  background: #C3C3C3;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.side_nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side_nav li a img {
  width: 30px;
}
.side_nav li .nav_title {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <img src="assets/images/logo_navbar/alphaLogo_nav_30x30.png" class="logo">
  <p class="navbar_brand">DashBoard</p>
</div>
<div class="nav_content">
  <div class="side_nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-  set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Audit</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Analytics</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Change</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Cost Analytics</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Governance</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Reports</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Feedback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: sorry I accidentally posted before completing my question

Comment: I tried resizing.. No scrollbars appeared !!

Comment: Actually, If you reduce the browser width, the contents do not shrink. Instead a scroll bar appears. Can You see the plunker too

Comment: Tried css media queries?

Comment: your style file don't have any media rules for your side bar. check css from here http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-sidebar-menu

Comment: Actually, I don't want for different media sizes. What I expect is a little responsive that If adjust the screen a little.It should adjust and the content should fit the screen..Instead of scroll bar.

Comment: If you don't want to differ width for different media then how is it supposed to `adjust` ? Nothing happens by itself, we have to `adjust` it!

Comment: Sorry @JonesVinothJoseph. I will try that. I think I am not too clear what I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Media queries..

Something like this:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 641px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 70px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 961px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 90px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

Go full screen and resize browser for effect

```css
/* Styles go here */

.topbar {
  height: 50px;
  background: #00a99d;
}
.topbar .logo {
  float: left;
  margin: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
}
.topbar .navbar_brand {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 0px 0px 42px;
}
.nav_content {
  float: left;
}
.side_nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  padding: 0;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.side_nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.side_nav li {
  list-style: none;
}
.side_nav .divider {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 0px 6px 0px 6px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #d9d9db;
}
.side_nav li a {
  padding: 13px 0px 16px 0px;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
}
.side_nav li a:hover {
  background: #C3C3C3;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.side_nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.side_nav li a img {
  width: 30px;
}
.side_nav li .nav_title {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
@media (min-width: 320px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 481px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 60px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 641px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 70px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 961px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 80px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1025px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 90px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1281px) {
  .side_nav {
    width: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <img src="assets/images/logo_navbar/alphaLogo_nav_30x30.png" class="logo">
  <p class="navbar_brand">DashBoard</p>
</div>
<div class="nav_content">
  <div class="side_nav">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-  set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Audit</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Analytics</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Change</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Cost Analytics</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Governance</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Reports</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a>
          <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/complete-set-icons/512/google512x512.png">
          <span class="nav_title">Feedback</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: can I auto adjust the height.

Comment: Inside similar media queries alter the `height` as i have altered the `width` in the code snippet above.

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap framework. It is already responsive.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

read the docs here